# capturing Alt+F+P jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is how I was able to capture `CTRL+C` in jQuery

```
$(window).bind('keydown', function (event) {
        if (event.ctrlKey || event.metaKey) {
            switch (String.fromCharCode(event.which).toLowerCase()) {
                case 'p':
                    event.preventDefault();
                    printFunc();
                    break;             
            }
        }
    });
```

How can i do the same for `ALT+F+P`

```
$(window).bind('keydown', function (event) {
          if (event.altKey || event.metaKey) {
            switch (String.fromCharCode(event.which).toLowerCase()) {
                case 'f': 
                    event.preventDefault();
//************ Need help for identifying p  **************
                  //  alert('Alt-f');
                   printFunc();
                    break;            
            }
        }
    });
```

I tried this also but no luck:

```
if (event.altKey && event.which == 70 && event.which == 80) {
       alert('Alt-f-p');
    }
```

Comment: You do realize that `event.which` can't possibly be `70` and `80` at the same time, right?

Comment: @cookiemonster I do. just showing all the ways i tried to solve the issue so that somebody can correct the mistake i made.

Comment: You might try using https://github.com/rheone/jquery.Chord

Comment: If you have a lot of shortcuts , i recommend you to use Moustrap javascript library

Comment: umm, you can't press F and P at the same time. just try it in notepad if you don't believe me.

Answer (score 1):

This works, but only if you do "p" before "f". In Chrome at least, Alt+F activates a browser function. **[Live demo (click).](http://jsbin.com/UrOhEmIz/1/edit)**

```
var pressed = {};
$(document).keydown(function(event) {
  //event.altKey 70 80
  var k = event.keyCode;
  if (event.altKey && (k == 70 || k == 80)) {
    pressed[k] = true;
    console.log(k);
  }
  if (pressed[70] && pressed[80]) {
    console.log('all pressed!');
  }
});

$(document).keyup(function() {
  pressed = {};
});
```

Perhaps you would want to adapt it to use something not conflicted?

Comment: ALT+F is going to be spoken for in almost every windows app.